# Isekai manga where a guy getting transported to his favorite game but as sss rank side character who's a mercenary and is fated to die

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character reincarnated in his favorite game but as a sss rank side character who's a mercenary who is fated to die by a demon. The hero's party open a giant door that unsealed the demons. The whole kingdom is up in flames, but he knows what's going on and changes his fate and kills the demon that was fated to kill him and is now with the hero's party.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You use "he" and "him" a lot, but it's not always clear which of the "main character" the demon or the hero you are referring to.  _Who_ knows "what's going on," the main character?  Also, where and when did you read this?  And what is "a sss rank ... character?"

Comment: the main character is not the demon nor the hero hes a side character that is very respected and was fated to die but  being he had know what had lied ahead of him he changed his fate and not had died

Comment: @Golden Jr - Was this story in full colour, or mostly black & white? Also, do you recall any specific weapons or powers that the mercenary used?

Comment: i think it was all black and white and the specific powers he used i cant recall but i think he was sword user i could be wrong though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[I'm Not the Hero!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shujinkou-ja-nai)*

> "Reincarnated as a **sub-character of a video game** that I used to play!?" After saving a girl and then getting run over by a car in the process, "I" was reincarnated as "Rex" in a video game world. Rex is handsome and has skills in all fields, but he is a helper character in the early stages. Though Rex has a high level, balanced skill set, and multitude of abilities…He's useless in the later stages of the game!!

Rex is described as an A-rank adventurer, not a mercenary, but the two are similar. He isn't explicitly described as being SSS-rank or having SSS stats, just that he's extremely strong for the opening scene. He's supposed to die in the early stages of the game, but uses his knowledge to avoid this. He uses a sword.

The plot of the opening is similar to what you described, but some of it was just thinking about the regular future, and didn't actually happen after he reincarnates. He meets the hero and his party, stops them from opening the door, and exits the cave. The city is still in flames, and manages to kill the Doom Demon that was supposed to kill him by using his in-game knowledge.

Comment: thank you very much @qazmlpok