# Searching for a manga about a mc that gets transported into a video game world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

In the plot, the mc gets transported into a video game he had played a lot in his childhood, and that there was a special controller the mc bought in order to play the game and activate skills. The main thing I remember about the plot was that the mc takes over the body of a villager npc girl's brother, who is a famous adventurer. In the beginning arc, when he found out he took over that character, he  immediately goes to a dungeon where the main character's team was about to open a sealed door containing the demon lord. He then stops them from opening it. Not sure if I am right, but I think I also remember reading about the fact that the mc gets a cheat regarding the controller he used when he was playing the game.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It was in black and white.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not _[Time Stop Hero](https://myanimelist.net/manga/124797/Jikan_Teishi_Yuusha)_, as while it is an isekai manga where the MC has a game controller, he appears to have retained his own body, rather than being reincarnated as an NPC's brother.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't. The mc used the controller in game to perform something called an arts skill I think and was the only character experienced enough of the party to do a double arts skill using the controller, when he transmigrated into the game world.

Comment: Also remembered reading that the game the mc played had tons of routes for the party. It was kind of like xenoblade chronicles.

Comment: https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/mini-world-of-endless-fun-awaits-novel has some similarities, but is a webnovel

Comment: You could try going through this list of manga with video game like elements: https://www.anime-planet.com/users/LupaLunae/lists/manga-with-game-elements-59246 (be aware, there are 240 of them...)

Answer (score 1):

This is *[I'm Not the Hero!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shujinkou-ja-nai)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261069):

> "Reincarnated as a sub-character of a video game that I used to play!?" After saving a girl and then getting run over by a car in the process, "I" was reincarnated as "Rex" in a video game world. Rex is handsome and has skills in all fields, but he is a helper character in the early stages. Though Rex has a high level, balanced skill set, and multitude of abilities…He's useless in the later stages of the game!!

The special controller is this:

[image: Pay to win]

However, if it has more of a role in the story, it hasn't happened yet. I don't know a good way to check the source novel.

The first thing he does is stop the hero's party from opening a door that would unleash a sealed demon, which would destroy a nearby town. Which gets destroyed anyway. He goes towards it and finds a girl who calls him brother.